# Windows Bat file run from Autosys - Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll

Tags: windows, batch-file, autosys

I have a question and wondering if you guys could help.. Here are the details -

Program Flow ->
Autosys Job -> Windows .bat job on network path-> Internally calls java program along with few other components

When the .bat runs through Autosys job, it  gives below warning and does partial processing and exits out without any failure 
(i guess the internal code might not have good error handling..but sadly I do not have access to view/modify the same). However, when I logon to that 
windows box and run the .bat file from cmd prompt, it works like a charm and throws no error.

Warning in Logs - "WARNING: Failed to load the sqljdbc_auth.dll"

Things I tried-
I tried creating a wrapper bat file in windows C drive (not the netwrok path where the actual .bat is in) and placed sqljdbc_auth.dll in that custom folder.
Job went to SU , after partial processing.

Appreciate your help.

Many Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect there is a `path` error. Try `echo %path%` just before calling your batch, even simply run

```
echo %path%>alogfile
call yourbatch
```

and if the displayed `path` doesn't include a directory in which your .dll resides, add it into the path before calling yourbatch.

It may very well be that `your` logon includes the required directory as part of `your` user-defined `path` and the username under which the job runs does not include the directory.

Or, you could try moving the dll into somewhere like `system32` which should be common to everyone.

(Windows should use the standard path-scanning algorithm to locate any required dll that isn't invoked from a full pathname)